# Crawling images and storing in multiple folders

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, web-crawler

I can not figure out how to deal with the following problem. I want to crawl multiple images from an URL which is stored in each row of a dataframe and store the images by their individual categoryId in a folder. However this is process possible, but right now there are some small bugs and I do not know how to fix it. The following code snippet demonstrates this process of downloading and storing the files:

```
import os

for x in range(df.shape[0]):
    ID = df.categoryId[x]

    print(ID)
    if not os.path.exists(ID):
        os.makedirs(ID)

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(df.image_url[x]), "{}/image{}.jpg".format(ID, x))
```

The problem is that in the first category (19) all images will be stored (of all categories), but there are actually only 165 files. The images for other category are stored correctly with their right amount of images. I also tried to count the number categories and distribute it over the different folder but it is not working.

```
df.categoryId.value_counts()

Output:
19    165
24     23
1       8
10      2
20      1
23      1
```

Answer (score -1):

You should really iterate over a DataFrame using something like `df.iterrows()`, which might solve your problem in itself.

```
import os

for x, (index, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    ID = row['categoryId']

    print(ID)
    if not os.path.exists(ID):
        os.makedirs(ID)

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(row['image_url']), "{}/image{}.jpg".format(ID, x))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I should fix this with df.iterrows(), however it does not solve the problem that the first folder is full of all images of all categories.